# Defensive Code to prevent Infinite Recursion in Parent/Child Hierarchy

Tags: c#, parent-child, stack-overflow

Given an *Object* as Such

```
public class Thing
{  
    public Thing() { this.children = new List<Thing>();}

    public int Id {get; set;}       
    public string Name {get; set;}      
    public List<Thing> children{ get; set;}

    public string ToString(int level = 0)
    {
        //Level is added purely to add a visual hierarchy
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(new String('-',level));
        sb.AppendLine($"id:{Id} Name:{Name}");          
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
                sb.Append(child.ToString(level + 1));
        }       
        return sb.ToString();
    }   
}
```

and if used (abused!?) in such a way

```
public static void Main()
{
    var root = new Thing{Id = 1,Name = "Thing1"};       
    var thing2 = new Thing{Id = 2,Name = "Thing2"};             
    var thing3 = new Thing{Id = 3,Name = "Thing3"};     
    root.children.Add(thing2);
    thing2.children.Add(thing3);                         
    thing3.children.Add(root);  //problem is here       
    Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());     
}
```

how does one be *defensive* about this kind of scenario.

This code as it stands produces a *stackoverflow, infinite recursion, or memory exceeded error*.

In a (IIS) website this was causing the w3 worker processes to crash, and eventually the app pool to shut down (Rapid-Fail Protection)

The code above is indicative only to reproduce the problem. In the actual scenario, the structure is coming from a database with Id and ParentId.

Database table structure similar to

```
CREATE TABLE Thing(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ParentThingId INT NULL //References self
)
```

The issue is that the creation of the 'things' by users is not preventing a incestuous relationship (i.e. a Parent could have children (who could have children etc.... that one eventually points at the parent again). One could put a constraint on the db to prevent the thing not being its own parent (makes sense), but depending on depth this could get ugly, and there is some argument that a circular reference may be required (we are still debating this....)

So arguably the structures can be circular, but if you want to render this kind of structure on a web page say as a `<ul><li><a>` tag kind of thing in a parent/child menu, how does one become proactive about dealing with this user generated data issue in code?

.NET fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b8LJwb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to include a collection of visited nodes in the recursive call. If visited before you are in a cycle.

```
public string ToString(int level = 0, HashSet<int> visited)
{
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
                if(visited.Add(child.Id))
                   sb.Append(child.ToString(level + 1, visited));
                else
                   //Handle the case when a cycle is detected.
        }       
        return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unfold the tree structure by putting each element on a stack or queue and popping items of there while the collection has items. In the while loop you put the children of each item on the queue.

If you care about the level of the item in the tree you need can use a helper object that stores that.

Edit:

While unfolding the tree you can put each item on a new list and use that as reference for circular problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you can a) eliminate that possibility of wanting to have circular references and b) guarantee that all children are already known of when that parent is created, its a great opportunity to make children an *immutable* collection that's only set via the constructor.

That gives you a class that, by structural recursion, you know cannot contain any loops, no matter how big the overall structure is. Something like:

```
public sealed class Thing
{  
    public Thing(IEnumerable<Thing> children) {
      this._children = children.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Thing> _children;

    public int Id {get; set;}       
    public string Name {get; set;}      
    public IEnumerable<Thing> children {
       get {
         return _children;
       }
    }

    public string ToString(int level = 0)
    {
        //Level is added purely to add a visual hierarchy
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(new String('-',level));
        sb.AppendLine($"id:{Id} Name:{Name}");          
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
                sb.Append(child.ToString(level + 1));
        }       
        return sb.ToString();
    }   
}
```

Now, of course, those conditions I have stated above are quite big "if"s, so you need to consider whether it's a good fit for you.

Comment: You said "there is some argument that a circular reference may be required (we are still debating this....)" - so I thought I'd take the opportunity to present something that could be used as a strong example of what opportunities are available if you can decide against having them.